# Sansa Clip not recognized

Tags: rhythmbox, sansa-clip

I just took the awesome plunge into linuxland, and am loving it so far!

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a HP G74 laptop, and everything but my Sansa Clip is working great!

I can it in and see a few folders in the clip, but none of my music shows up , in Rhythmbox or in folders. It is in MSC mode, and it was in MSC mode when I put the music on there; though I was running Win7 at that time.

Any help? I tried the adding a blank `.is_audio_player` file to the root of the clip, but it did not help either.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried a firmware update of your Sansa ? (if it exists). 
My Sansa(fuse) has not problems at all with Ubuntu. Works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

When you did the blank `.is_audio_player` file, the problem was you left the body of the document blank.

You've actually got to put `.is_audio_player` in the document. Just naming it `.is_audio_player` won't make any difference.

So just open the document in the Clip and type `.is_audio_player`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nope. that didn't do the trick. Found a few other suggestions online with other text to put in the .is_audio_player file, but no luck. Maybe it's just time for format and start over. :-/

Comment: I just updated the firmware, but it's still acting the same. Another one of those problems only I seem to have, it seems.